# How could I change an array size from 2D to 3D with Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, netcdf

I'm analyzing the output of a Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) written with python.
This is trained with the same NetCDF data with Temperature as a variable of interest. Every data is
defined by one time step with a grid size of `71x57`, `(71, 57)[latitude, longitude]` .

The output predicted from the CNN is an array `(333, 2907)`  where `333` are all the timesteps and `2907` is obtain (I suppose) from latitude and longitude. The problem arises when I have to plot a map of one time step of my variable of interest because I have to create a map with latitude and longitude `71x57` but my `Temperature.shape` is `(333, 2907)` and I would need it as `(333, 71, 57)`.

I think it's probably a problem of how the model creates those output array or maybe I'm missing something in the "array handling". I tried a few things found here as [.reshape()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634634/convert-2d-array-to-3d-numpy-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165820/apply-mask-array-2d-to-3d) but nothing worked.
Could you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain how exactly "nothing worked."  `*.reshape(333, 71, 57)` or even `*.reshape(-1, 71, 57)` should work in this instance just fine.

Comment: 71*57 is not 2907.  So obviously the reshape won't work.  You need to read up on that CNN to identify what that 2907 dimension represents.  We can't guess that for you!